# PDO transactions?

Tags: mysql, transactions, currency

Do I need to lock tables if I use PDO transactions?

If user a has 50 money and transfers 50 to user b, will PDO transaction make sure they all get executed without error?

Also if say I have a if statement like,

```
if ($user['money'] > 500) {
     $dbc ->beginTransaction();
     .........
     $dbc ->commit();
}
```

How can I ensure that the value of the users' money doesn't change meaning the query shouldn't run, while the transaction is running??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Transaction process is guaranteed by SQL server. If beginTransaction() succeeds, commit() succeeds and your SQL server and table supports transactions, then you can be sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

PDO is an abstraction layer, so it depends on your database. MySQL supports transactions, but only for InnoDB tables. Otherwise only with table locks (which is not the same). SQLite always supports transactions. Another database might never.

Transactions still require YOU (the developer) to create and verify the logic. The database doesn't know what's right (correct, not just) and what's wrong (incorrect). You do, so you have to create a script that calls BEGIN and COMMIT/ROLLBACK when appropriate.

Also worth noting: a transaction isn't automatically ROLLBACKed after a database error. (Maybe some databases or DBALs do, but it's not standard and you shouldn't count on it.) Which means YOU have to check the result/response/feedback of every query AND act appropriately (eg. by calling a ROLLBACK).